# How to convert NSString to char?

Tags: nsstring, char

I'm trying to convert an NSString to a single char.  When I write `[[NSLocale] currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]`, I get `@","`.  How can I convert this to `','`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unichar character = [myNSString characterAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Note this is not a C char - as unicode might be more than one byte

Comment: will be.  its always 2 bytes ain't it.